# Why src in this.id.src undefined (in debugger) [inside an iife]

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, event-listener, src, iife

Why is the src in this.id.src undefined in debugger? I don't understand why this doesn't work. I've had this working before, but with a specific id (not this.id) Does anyone have any suggestions?

```js
document.getElementById("a1").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction (id) {
 console.log(this.id);  // works
 this.id.src="images/red.jpg";
}
```

```html
<div>
<img id="a1" src="images/black.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: `this.id.src` means *the property called "src" located on the object that's the value of the property called "id" on the object "this"*. The value of the "id" attribute of a DOM node will always be a string, so it will *never* have a "src" property. You probably want just `this.src`.

Comment: There's no IIFE in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `src` property on the `id` property. You must used it directly `this.src`. And the parameter that is passed to the function is the event not the id:

```js
document.getElementById("a1").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction(e) {
  this.src = "http://via.placeholder.com/150x150";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="a1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
</div>
```